# C++ throwing error "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'"

Tags: c++, bad-alloc

I'm trying to run the following code, which should get user input, place it in a string, copy that string over to an array of chars, extract the first character to another array of chars, and finally get the rest of it after a space to an array of `int`s. But, it throws an error and I can't tell why:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of `std::bad_alloc`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char ID[15];
    int score[15];
    float avg[3];
    int i;

    cout<< "Hello there!:\n";

    string name;

    for (i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {

        cout<< "Please enter a ID:";
        cin >> name;

        char* temp = new char[name.size()+1];

        name.copy(temp, name.size() + 1);

        ID[i] = temp[0];

        temp = new char[name.size()-2];

        name = name.substr(2,name.length());
        name.copy(temp, name.size() + 1);

        score[i] = atoi(temp);
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Name" << "      " << "Average" << endl;

    for (i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
        cout << ID[i] << "           "<< score[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What line does the debugger say that the `bad_alloc` was thrown from? My guess is it came from the `temp = new char[name.size()-2];` - Think about the cases where `temp = new char[name.size()-2];` could result in a bad alloc.

Comment: `i <= 15` -> `i < 15`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think real hard about what this piece of code is doing:

```cpp
temp = new char[name.size()-2];
name = name.substr(2,name.length());
name.copy(temp, name.size() + 1);
```

If `name.size()` is less than 2 characters, the `new[]` is invalid.  But even if `name.size()` were greater than 2, say 5, then you would allocate `temp` as only `3` characters *without* room for the null-terminator, but then you would copy 3 characters *and* the null-terminator into `temp`. So you are likely to corrupt memory.

That said, there are other problems with the rest of your code, too:

- Your loops are going out of bounds of your `ID[]` and `score[]` arrays. You need to use `<` instead of `<=`.
- You are leaking memory with your `new[]`'s, since you don't `delete[]` the memory you allocate.  In fact, there is really no need for the `temp` strings at all, so you should just get rid of them completely.
- You say there is a space character after the 1st character. But your use of `operator>>` will not read any characters after that space, because that is where `operator>>` stops reading.  Use `std::getline()` instead when you need to read a string with spaces in it.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char ID[15];
    int score[15];
    string name;

    cout << "Hello there!:\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {

        cout << "Please enter a ID:";
        getline(cin, name);

        ID[i] = name[0];

        name = name.substr(2,name.size());

        score[i] = atoi(name.c_str()); // <-- prefer std::stoi() instead...
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Name" << "      " << "Average" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
        cout << ID[i] << "           " << score[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, it would be simpler to write this without the use of `std::string` at all, let `operator>>` read directly into your arrays handling the spaces between them for you, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char ID[15];
    int score[15];

    cout << "Hello there!:\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {

        cout << "Please enter a ID:";
        cin >> ID[i];
        cin >> score[i];
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Name" << "      " << "Average" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
        cout << ID[i] << "           " << score[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this works, but I ran into a minor issue: Pressing enter inserts the value typed then runs the loop again and inserts an empty string on the second. How can I avoid that?

Comment: @elpeleq42 please elaborate. Which example is exhibiting that behavior, and what is the EXACT input you are typing in to reproduce it? Please be more specific.

Comment: oh never mind, the second code doesn't have the same issue for some reason. I'm sorry for the newbie questions